# entity framework does not load navigation property after adding object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have MVC project and EF6 model.

[image]

LazyLoading is enabled. In controller I have the following action

```
    public ActionResult AddStage(int projectId, int employeeId)
    {
        using(var context = new TestProjectEntities())
        {
            var project = context.Projects.Find(projectId);
            if (project != null)
            {
                var stage = new Stage() {EmployeeID = employeeId, StageType = 1};
                project.Stages.Add(stage);
                context.Stages.Add(stage);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            ListEmployees(project);
        }

        return Redirect("Index");
    }

    private void ListEmployees(Project project)
    {
        var names = new List<string>();
        foreach(var stage in project.Stages)
        {
            if (stage.Employee != null)
            {
                names.Add(stage.Employee.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

But in ListEmployees method stage.Employee == null in foreach statement.
Why?

And if i call AddStage for second time then stage.Employee != null in ListEmployee

Comment: And is it saved in your database? Did you declare the Employee property in stage as virtual ?

Comment: Data saved in database. Employee property is virtual

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're simply setting the foreign-key property (`Stage.EmployeeID`) without setting the navigation-property (`Stage.Employee`).

Usually, after calling `SaveChanges()`, EF would update the navigation property as well. But, since the `Stage` object is created manually by you it's not tracked (using a DynamicProxy) and you'll have to explicitly fix-up the relationship:

```
context.Entry(stage).Reference(c => c.Employee).Load();
```

Another approach would be to fetch the `Employee` and use it instead of setting the foreign-key property:

```
var employee = context.Employees.Find(employeeId);
var stage = new Stage() { Employee = employee, StageType = 1};
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`new Stage()`

Don't do this with EF objects. You won't get the correct proxy object that can lazy load navigation properties. You need to use something like `dbContext.Set<Stage>().Create()`

Comment: Using `dbContext.Set<Stage>().Create()` instead of creating a new object was the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I think having the `EmployeeID` in the `Stage` class and having the `Employee` object have an `ID` property is probably confusing things.  I dont actually see where you assign an `Employee` to the `Stage`.  I would expect to see something like this:

```
var stage = new Stage() {EmployeeID = employeeId, StageType = 1, Employee = stageManager};
```